# Access to a textbox in gridview and set its value

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i have the textbox with its ID txtPassword.

```
<FooterTemplate>
           <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
           <asp:Button ID="PasswordGenerator" runat="server" Text="Generete new Password" OnClick="PasswordGenerator_Click" />
</FooterTemplate>
```

and when a user click on "Generete new Password" its goes to this function, and the txtPassword textbox will filled automatcly with the generated password.

```
protected void PasswordGenerator_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int length = 6;
    const string valid = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890";
    StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
    Random rnd = new Random();
    while (0 < length--)
    {
        res.Append(valid[rnd.Next(valid.Length)]);
    }

    ((TextBox)GridView1.FindControl("txtPassword")).Text = res.ToString();
}
```

but i cant access it from the C# code. 
so i search and i found that i need to do with with findcontrol() but its still no working.

please help :)

thanks!

Comment: If you simply put txtPassword, does the Intellisense show something?

Comment: no, its not show it. and the reason is beacuse the txtPassword is under a Gridview tag.

Comment: If it is in the gridView and the Id name is as shown, then findControl should have returned the control. But it isn't. I cannot but suspect the control is not really in the gridview, or if it is, it has different name. Maybe you can check the Controls which the GridView has by checking the Property "Controls" of the GridView. You could see what are the controls which the GridView really has there...

Comment: It seems like your control is in the footer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the correct way:

```
TextBox Password = GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtPassword") as TextBox;

if (Password != null)
    Password.Text = "Hello";
```